# Use value of one text item into report

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to use text value from one tablix to another. But I am getting error like below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Lookup (single value) LookupSet (if its multiple value):
[LookupSet function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookupset-function?view=sql-server-2017)